# Routing error no route matches 'GET' /ckeditor/pictures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor

Am using ckeditor-rails for my app, I successfuly added the gem, installed, configured, and awesomely working, but when i click on browse button, the routing error displays on the screen, here am attaching the screenshot for reference,[image]

and this is my optional configured config.js file details:-

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";  
    config.toolbar_basic = [
        [ 'Save', '-', 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord',
        '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ],
        [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline',
        '-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
        ['Smiley', 'Preview', 'Find', 'Replace', 'Link', 'Unlink', '-', 'Image' ],
        ['Table', 'Font', 'FontSize', '-', 'TextColor', 'BGColor', '-','Maximize']
    ];
    config.uiColor = "#eff4ff"
    config.toolbar = config.toolbar_basic;
};
```

My environment details: Ubuntu 12.04, ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.2.13.

Rake routes log:

```
  ckeditor_rails_engine        /ckeditor                                                
Ckeditor::Rails::Engine
Routes for Ckeditor::Rails::Engine:
```

Please help me! many Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `routes.rb` file. It should contain something like `mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'` as per the gem documentation.

**Edit:** it seems ckeditor-rails doesn't provide the file uploader component from ckeditor (CKFinder). You can give a try to the ckeditor gem (https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor), that provides that functionality in combination with paperclip. I've used it successfuly in many projects.

Comment: Hi @sjalme, Thank you for your quick response, Yes, I tried mount Ckeditor::Rails::Engine => '/ckeditor', but the error remains same.., Please help me.

Comment: Could you post then the output of `rake routes` ?

Comment: you mean the whole rake log file..??

Comment: If it's too long, the output of `rake routes|grep -i ckeditor` should suffice.

Comment: here is the log file, thanks for that command..lovely..

ckeditor_rails_engine        /ckeditor                                                Ckeditor::Rails::Engine
Routes for Ckeditor::Rails::Engine: